# Magento Memory issue for installing extensions

Tags: magento2, extensions, php-7, memory

I am really stuck at the moment.

I keep getting the following error:
"*Your current PHP memory limit is 512M. Magento 2 requires it to be set to 756M or more. As a user with root privileges, edit your php.ini file to increase memory_limit. (The command php --ini tells you where it is located.) After that, restart your web server and try again*."

When i speak to my hosting (go daddy) the confirm that i have it set to 756M, also when i check myself it shows the local memory as 756M. However when i try update or install and extension i get the error.

I have seen posts where people are saying its issues with cron but my cron seems to be running okay.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks
Craig

Comment: Do you install your extensions by CLI?

Comment: No been trying via the GUI in the admin panel. Won't let me update or install anything due to the memory issue.

Comment: In this case I'm not able to help, if you use CLI to install, you can pass the -dmemory_limit to yout command, like this: `php -dmemory_limit=512M bin/magento module:enable Vendor/Module`

Comment: have u checked phpinfo. create .https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643880/how-can-i-create-a-phpinfo.php-page

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, copy and paste this as one command. Run it from the root of your Magento installation, aka the folder that contains your main index.php file.

```
find . -name '.htaccess' -exec sed -i '' s/756M/2048M/g {} + && \
find . -name '.htaccess' -exec sed -i '' s/768M/2048M/g {} + && \
find . -name '.user.ini' -exec sed -i '' s/756M/2048M/g {} + && \
find . -name '.user.ini' -exec sed -i '' s/768M/2048M/g {} +
```

There are several files that limit your php memory_limit. This targets those files and sets the max limit to 2048M.

On that note, 2048M is an ideal memory limit for Magento 2. The command above doesn't necessarily "give" you 2048M of memory, it just raises Magento's pre-set memory limit but you may still be capped elsewhere.

I should also mention that changing the memory limit in your htaccess file does not affect your command line memory limit, it affects the memory limit when accessing the site in a web browser.

Comment: Cheers Shawn - I'll give this a bash.

Comment: Shawn - got the following error: sed: can't read s/756M/2048M/g: No such file or directory

Comment: In that case, just remove lines 1 and 3 from the command. It usually doesn't throw an error if it doesnt exist but on some operating systems it does.

Comment: Still the same bro "sed: can't read s/768M/2048M/g: No such file or directory"

Comment: 3 questions. What operating system are you running this on? Are you certain you're running it from the root of your Magento installation(the one that contains the app, bin, vendor dirs)? Also, can you check that you have .htaccess, pub/.htaccess, .user.ini, and pub/.user.ini?

Comment: Hi Shawn, sorry been away on Holiday. This is the output for the type of linux:Linux version 2.6.32-896.16.1.lve1.4.54.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@buildfarm03.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed May 2 07:43:19 EDT 2018

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue, This's my code to run it: `php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade`.